# Twisted - Python3 TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'factory'

Tags: python, python-3.x, twisted, twisted.internet

I'm writing some python software that polls a modbus connection and stores the data in an SQL database. To see if the machine is working as a quick test, I'm making a simple console style "HMI" that you can telnet into. Here is the offending code, and error.

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol, Factory
from twisted.internet.endpoints import TCP4ServerEndpoint
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.internet import task
from twisted.internet import protocol

#from screenhelp import ScreenHelp ** Not relevant to error


class Screen(Protocol):

    def __init__(self, factory):
        self.factory = factory
        self.connection = False
        self.loop = task.LoopingCall(screenRefresh)
        self.loopDeferred = None
        self.stack = []
        self.cs = ScreenHelp()

    def connectionMade(self):
        self.loopDeferred = self.loop.start(self,5)

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        self.loop.stop(self)

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        self.stack.append(data)

    def screenRefresh(self):

        #self.transport.write(self.cs.clr()) ** Not relevent - issues clear screen command.
        for x in self.stack:
            self.transport.write(x)

class ScreenFactory(Factory):
    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return Screen()


def main():
    endpoint1 = TCP4ServerEndpoint(reactor, 64000)
    endpoint1.listen(ScreenFactory)
    reactor.listenTCP(5000, fact)
    reactor.run()


if __name__ == "__main__":
     main()
```

The error is:

```
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/twisted/internet/protocol.py", line 135, in buildProtocol
    p = self.protocol()
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'factory'
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Is that the whole error?

Comment: That error message doesn't seem to have anything to do with the code you posted. The line `p = self.protocol()` does not appear. However, in your actual posted code, you'll get a similar error because you are not passing a `factory` parameter when you instantiate your `Screen` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be related to your problem:

In this section, you call `Screen()` without any arguments:

```
class ScreenFactory(Factory):
    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return Screen()
```

However, earlier you defined `Screen` to take a `factory` argument:

```
class Screen(Protocol):
    def __init__(self, factory):
        ...
```